# Powershell v2 Get-Eventlog: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, elevated-privileges

I am using Powershell v2 this is my script

```
param([string]$Sender_IP=$(throw " Sender's IP is required."))
$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -computername $Sender_IP `
        | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
        | Select-Object -First 2 `
        | foreach-Object {
            $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
            $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
            $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
            $eventList += $row
            }
$UserId = $eventList[1].UserName

$UserID
```

The only time the code works is if I pass in the IP address of my current server.

I am logged into this server using my administrator credentials and I even selected Run-As Administrator to run powershell.

Why am I getting the following error when using other IP addresses that I can ping and have administrative access to:

```
Get-EventLog : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At script_path_and_name.ps1:5 char:13
+ Get-EventLog <<<<  "Security" -computername $Sender_IP `
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

@Adi Inbar

Remote Registry Service is running, and firewall is off. Yet it is not working.

And when I try running with a service account, it doesn't work either.

But the strange thing is, when I run with service account, and enter in my own IP address I get error,

```
Get-EventLog : Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

Comment: Make sure the Remote Registry Service is running on the target computers. Also, try momentarily taking down the firewall on one of them to see whether that's getting in the way.

Comment: Remote Registry Service is running, and firewall is off. Yet it is not working. And when I try running with a service account, it doesn't work either. But the strange thing is, when I run with service account, and enter in my own IP address I get error, Get-EventLog : Requested registry access is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

When you run it as the service account on your machine is the Powershell prompt elevated?

I was getting that error (registry access not allowed) when running Powershell in a non-elevated prompt on my machine.

Do you know what the Execution Policy is on the remote machines?  I'm not sure if it matters as the cmdlet remotes itself, but it might be worth checking.

Also, just a FYI:

The Pipe is a natural line break anyway, you don't need the backticks (just don't leave any spaces after the pipe).

For example:

```
cmdlet1 |
 cmdlet2 |
  cmdlet 3
```